# Error for build in android studio 4.1 with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I install the new version of Android Studio but when i want to build my project and sync with gradle this error show. What should i do to fix this error?

gradle setting:(gradle-wrapper.properties)

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

error:

```
org.gradle.process.internal.JvmOptions.<init>(Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileCollectionFactory;)Vorg.gradle.process.internal.JvmOptions.<init>(Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileCollectionFactory;)V
```

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: it's the full error. nothing show when click to sync gradle.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do a build from command line?

Comment: @PiRocks It does build successfully on the terminal when I tried `./gradlew assembleDebug` but on Android Studio, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Either You have not set the kotlin version correctly in **project level** build.gradle

And also change the **gradle-6.5-bin.zip** to **gradle-6.7-all.zip**
This might work

Comment: I change gradle version and set kotlin version but didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Remove old Android studio before installing new.